# How to get the current version of app which installed on user mobile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apk

I want to know how we can get the current version of app which is installed on users mobile using nodejs. The thing is, I want to restrict some features for users who Have installed older versions of my app, I am going to check this on a button event, if it’s older versions ignore otherwise run the script. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a `yourap://page` link to switch to your app. Then ping your server from inside the app

Comment: In the new version of App, you can pass current version with request to your Node.js with params, on Node.js side you can check like: `if version && version > xx`, otherwise, if no version passed or version is older, you skip the logic.